# How do I add multiple associations at once in rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these two simple models:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
end
```

I can create a menu and create ingredients for that same menu but for situations where there are a lot of ingredients like say 20? it's tedious.

How do I go about being able to select a number of ingredients I want to create for a menu and get the form to generate that number of fields blank and waiting for input?

Comment: Check out `cocoon` gem. https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: Without seeing what your form looks like, I recommend watching the two screencasts (RailsCasts) Ryan Bates made. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: @ArunKumar Cocoon solved the issue. Post as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're looking for dynamic nested forms, you should try using `cocoon` gem which makes your life a lot easy.

For more information, have a look at https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 2):

with rails and no gem:  You can set nested attributes in your menu model and use fields_for in your menu form to add inputs and create it's ingridients.

read about nested attributes in forms
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

api reference for the method you're looking :
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

This way everytime you create a menu (form) you can add also attributes for ingridients.